# Ambiguous setter methods causing issue with assigning property value

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, configuration-files

I am having a problem when setting a property of a bean that has ambiguous setter methods.

The issue is the hostConfiguration.host property of the HttpClient has 3 possible methods to use:

1. HostConfiguration.setHost(String host)
2. HostConfiguration.setHost(HttpHost host)
3. HostConfiguration.setHost(URI host)

Here is my bean definition:

```
<bean id="primaryClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <property name="hostConfiguration.host">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost" >
            <constructor-arg value="somelink.com"/>
            <constructor-arg value="443"/>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol">
                    <constructor-arg value="https"/>
                    <constructor-arg ref="sslProtocolSocketFactory"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="443"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is the stack:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'primaryClient' defined in class path resource [spring/test-merchantlink-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
>   PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'hostConfiguration.host'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'host': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

How can I get around this? I'm using spring 2.5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically having overloaded setters violates the JavaBeans specification and is therefore not supported by spring. You can see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4931 for more details.

As you probably did not make the HttpClient and thus cannot change it, one solution would be the use of a factory bean. This would look something like this:

```
<bean id="httpClientFactory" class="my.package.HttpClientFactory"/>

<bean id="primaryClient" factory-bean="httpClientFactory" factory-method="create">
```

You would implement the `create()` method on `my.package.HttpClientFactor` to set-up and return your factory.

If there are specific parameters you want to set in the XML config rather than in code, you could add constructor arguments to `my.package.HttpClientFactor`.

Comment: Thank you. This does make sense, however I figured that Spring would be intelligent enough to determine which method call to make based on the parameter type passed in.

Comment: I agree. Their reasoning seems to be backward compatibility and sticking with the spec.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid overloading property setters that you want to be able to wire using IoC. When you do need two setters for (logically) the same property, you should use different setter names ... and javadoc comments to explain what is going on.

There are same issues on http://forum.spring.io that describe your same problem and the better solution is the rename all methods.

[Link1](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/37193-does-spring-support-overloading-of-setter-methods)

[Link2](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/47207-overloaded-setter-problem)

[Link3](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/72171-setter-method-overloading)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to specify explicitly the expected class name to avoid ambiguity between the multiple setters available.

May be something like:

```
<bean id="primaryClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <property name="hostConfiguration.host">
        <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost" >
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
                <value>somelink.com</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg type="int">
                <value>443</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol">
                    <constructor-arg value="https"/>
                    <constructor-arg ref="sslProtocolSocketFactory"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="443"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. The problem is one level higher when setting the hostConfiguration.host property. Not on the HttpHost bean. I have individually created that one without problems outside the scope of the HttpClient bean definition.